# How do I move a piece of standard header or paragraph element down

Tags: html, css

Ok, sorry I don't have any code to post but it's pretty simple.

I have a regular `<h1> ...</h1>` block of text that has been centered but I want to move it... Say maybe down 20 px.

How would I do this?

(I don't have a lot of experience with CSS)

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way to do this is like this if you want to use css inline:

```
<h1 style="margin-top:20px">your text here</h1>
```

now if you have a style sheet made and linked to the document head such as

```
<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

then you can simple target the parent div and do the same thing like this

```
.parentcontainter h1{
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

your html should look something like this

```
<div class="parentcontainer">
   <h1>your text here</h1>
</div>
```

the second option will give you more controll in the long run and make it much easier to make changes if you have a lot of pages using the same styling.

Answer (score 0):

`h1` will have a default margin, but you can increase that. Try for example `margin-top: 2em`, which is twice the font-size of that element. (The default margin top and bottom would probably be already 1em, depending on the browser, so defining `margin-top` as 20px would not have much effect - just try different values to get what you want)

Comment: setting margin-top as 20px will move it 20px in the viewport scaling it will have the defined effect, you can also try using vh, i dont like em because of bad scaling inherited from the parent div when you over use them.

Comment: @AnthonyMoore As I wrote - every browser already applies a default margin, usually 1em (= the font-size of that h1), so `margin-top: 20px` will *overwrite*  that default margin, which in most cases will even result in less margin than before.  Another way would be to write `margin-top: calc(1em + 20px), which would add 20 px to the browser's default margin, if that is 1em. (just try it to see what I mean)

Comment: i use a normalize on all my projects and i change those behaviors as i need to in my css. however i think he was asking for some literaly how to because of his dont have much css experience comment, im not sure he was looking for the technical disagreement about em vs other measurement units

Comment: @AnthonyMoore I didn't write about em or px, but I emphasized that there is are default margins in any browser, so `margin-top: 20px` will not *add* 20 px to the default marging, but *replace* the default margin, resulting in not-that-much difference to the default (probably even less margin-top than the default).

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you will need to use css on your `<h1>.......</h1>`

```
<style>
h1 {
margin-top:20px;
}
</style>
```